# Add a block to a render array

Tags: blocks, theming

I have a block I would like to add it to my renderable array (given to a page callback), with prefix and suffix - what's the cleanest way to do this?

I understand I can do it this way:

```
$markup = '';
if ($block = block_load('views','results_anonymous-block')) {
    $block_content = _block_render_blocks(array($block));
    $build = _block_get_renderable_array($block_content);
    $markup = drupal_render($build);
}


$content['page'] = array(

    '#markup' => $markup,
);

return $content;
```

But wondered if there was a better way (e.g. without rendering the block or using the private function).

Comment: Why don't just put a region where you need it, and put your block in that region?

Comment: You need to get the block in render array format and attach it to your render array. There are several answers about this in this site, I guess. I udnerstand that you want the block 'inside' your render array, otherwise you can use standard block system.

Comment: In the main content section? before or after the main content or inside the content section?

Comment: Inside, so I can add further markup before and after. (e.g. a general solution where the block is nested)

Comment: Care to leave a comment for the downvote? Seems a prefectly reasonable question to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modules provide their block titles and contents through implementations of [hook_block_view()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21block%21block.api.php/function/hook_block_view/7). If you're looking for something similar to your posted code that doesn't rely on calls to private functions, what's below should give you a render-ready array that you can place anywhere within another render array.

```
$renderable_block_data = module_invoke('views', 'block_view', 'results_anonymous-block');
$renderable_block_contents = $renderable_block_data['content'];
```

Caveat: while the docs for D7's version of hook_block_view() suggest that the returned "content" key should be a render array, some modules/blocks may be implemented in such a way that they return plain HTML strings, in which case you'd need to put the content in a #markup element before adding them to your parent render array.

Further discussion can be found in this [drupal.org post](https://www.drupal.org/node/26502).